# How to change the color of lines as part of a plot based on a separate vector of values?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a collection of values stored in a 350x130 matrix, *r*, that I'm using to create a simple plot in Matlab:

```
figure;
plot(r)
```

Is there a way to color the resulting lines from *r* using another 350x1 vector, *v*?  V contains a collection of integers, in this case, that vary from 1 to 4.

I'm imaging the call would look something like this, where, again, *r* is 350x130 and *v* is 350x1:

```
figure;
plot(r,v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define some example data:

```
r = rand(10,15);
v = randi(4,1,15);
```

#### Method 1 (more fun): using a comma-separated list

This creates a cell array and transforms it into a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to call `plot` as `plot(x1, y1, s1, x2, y2, s2, ...)`. The colors are limited to be defined as `plot`'s [linespec strings](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec) (such as `'g'` or `'c+'`).

```
linespecs = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'm'};
c = repmat({1:size(r,1)}, 1, size(r,2));
c(2,:) = num2cell(r, 1);
c(3,:) = linespecs(v);
plot(c{:})
```

#### Method 2 (more readable and flexible): using a loop

```
linespecs = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'm'};
hold on
for k = 1:size(r,2)
    plot(r(:,k), linespecs{v(k)})
end
```

This method allows using a [colormap](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/colors-1.html) to specify **arbitrary colors**, not limited to linespec strings:

```
colors = winter(4); % arbitrary colormap
hold on
for k = 1:size(r,2)
    plot(r(:,k), 'color', colors(v(k),:))
end
```

Comment: This is great!  Method 1 was exactly what I was after, though slight adjustments needed for the case I specified above

linespecs = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'm'};
c = repmat({1:size(r,2)}, 1, size(r,1));
c(2,:) = num2cell(r, 2);
c(3,:) = linespecs(v);
plot(c{:})